# Location subfields problem to render in teaser template node

Tags: 7, theming, location

I have tried render only two array´s parameters. Street and postal code but don´t display anything this code.

```
<?php print render($content['field_mapa']['und'][0]['street']); ?>and <?php print render($content['field_mapa']['und'][0]['city']); ?>
```

However with this code print all parameters.

```
<?php  print render($content['field_mapa']); ?>
```

I don´t understand where is the problem with this field.

Comment: do you work with [subfields](https://www.drupal.org/project/subfields) module?

Comment: No, only location field. Show the nodes in a view with a custom teaser template. And in this teaser i try to print render the street and postal code of this location field. However if i make print render $content about the field complete display all values of this location field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location field module wrap fields inside `#location` so try with :

```
<?php print render($content['field_mapa'][0]['#location']['street']); ?>
```

and

```
<?php print render($content['field_mapa'][0]['#location']['city']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i´m going to test this, but look like that this WORKS !!!! Thank you Berramou and 4k4 for edit the post.

Comment: i'm glad that help, mark the answer as the accepted, in case someone needs it in the future.

Comment: Ok, i´m new here and i´m learn the structure. Sorry